# python script to submit webpage checkbox request

Tags: javascript, python, checkbox

I want to a script to click the checkbox on a webpage. The checkbox source code looks like below:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='checkMe' name='checkMe' onclick='javascript:submitHome();'/><label for='checkMe'>Click here&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/goes/LogOutAction.do">Cancel</a>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform a action on a website. I'd suggest you use 'Dryscrape' library. Their documentation is pretty extensive!
In this case using dryscrape you'd have to do following steps.

## initiate a session

```
import dryscrape
sess = dryscrape.Session(base_url='baseUrl.com')
sess.visit('/')
button = sess.at_xpath('//*[@id="checkME"]') # This looks for the type CheckME
button.click()
```

Please refer back to https://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ if you got any issues!